# Add a value to table fields (lua)

Tags: lua, lua-table

guys!

Can you help me, please!

I want to add a number to a table, and I want to have it like this:

```
A={1,2,3}
B=A+5
--- now B is {6,7,8}
```

I don't want to create any classes, additional modules. May be some kind of extension to global table?

I think it can be done via global __add overrides.. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

```
A = setmetatable({1,2,3},
  {
    __add = function (t, add)
      assert(type(add) == "number", "invalid addend! number expected")
      local result = {}
      for i,v in ipairs(t) do
        result[i] = v + add
      end
      return result
    end
  })

B = A + 5    
print(table.concat(B, ","))
C = A + "f"
```

Comment: Hi! Can we make it without setting A to a metatable? I mean.. change global operators, override global metatable, or debug? BTW, thank you for this method too

Comment: no unless you change Lua in C each table that you want to add something to needs a metatable that implements __add

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by iterating through the table with ipairs and setting each element of B to the sum of the number and the corresponding element of A

For example

```
local B = {};
local numberToAdd = 5;
for i, v in ipairs(A) do
    B[i] = v + numberToAdd;
end
```

A metatable can also be used to have the syntax `B = A + 5`. You would use the same code as the example, but you would need to use `setmetatable` on `A` then set the __add function of the metatable to the example code.

Comment: Thank you, I know this method, it's the usual way.. I want to make it with '+' operatrors, but not using metatable on A, maybe we can change Global, or Debug tables?